# Types of circular acceleration?

Tags: classical-mechanics

To my knowledge there are three types of acceleration when a body (e.g. a rod) is moving in a circle about an axis. These are:

1. Angular acceleration : this is the rate of change of angular velocity.
2. Tangential acceleration : this is the linear acceleration of the system in a tangential direction to the circle and equals the radius times the angular acceleration.
3. Radial/centripetal acceleration : this is the linear acceleration of the system that is directed inwards towards the center of the circle.

I also think there are two types of velocity:

1. Linear velocity: this is its velocity in the tangential direction and is constantly changing
2. Angular velocity or angular frequency: this is the rate of change of angle.

Is the above correct? And have I missed anything?

Comment: yes. but angular frequency is defined as number of rotations per second.

Comment: Is this the same as angular speed I.e. The first derivative of angle with respect to time?

Comment: Could you please check the spelling? It's annoying to read things like: _accilration_.

Comment: No. Frequency is defined as 2π*θ/t where theta is the angle rotated for a time t. You maybe tempted to equate frequency to angular velocity. But it is not so. Angular velocity = dθ/dt. Angular frequency= (2π*∫_0^t▒〖x(t)dt〗)/t

Comment: Sorry about my spelling i am dyslexic. Is angular speed i.e. the ω we use for centripetal frequency, the same as angular velocity

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No. Frequency is defined as 2π*θ/t where theta is the angle rotated for a time t. You maybe tempted to equate frequency to angular velocity. But it is not so. Angular velocity = dθ/dt. Angular frequency= 2*pi*(Integral of x over time interval t)/t

Comment: This isn't true.  Angular velocity and angular frequency are the same thing (well, angular frequency is the magnitude of the angular velocity. But there's no $2\pi$ running around). "Frequency" and "angular frequency" differ by a factor of $2\pi$, but not angular velocity and angular frequency. If you've seen a textbook claim that they are different, it is using non-standard terminology. See, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency)

Answer (score 0):

No it's not correct, or at least it's headed in the wrong direction.  Properly, you define acceleration, in either 2 or 3 dimensions as fits your situation, by means of vector coefficients.  You can use Cartesian (x and y) systems or you can use Polar (radius and angle) systems, and report/calculate the acceleration components for each vector component.)

In 3D, those expand to (x,y,z) cartesian,  (rho, theta, phi (polar angle) in spherical polar coordinates, and a couple other possibilities as well.

Comment: Sorry does this mean my definitions are wrong??

Comment: His definitions seem right except for the fact that he termed angular velocity and frequency as one.

Comment: @anuraag fair enough -- I wanted to stress that there aren't "three kinds of acceleration." There's only one.

Comment: Does angular velocity = angular frequency for uniform circular motion??

Comment: @Joseph angular velocity=( angular frequency/ 2πr). where r is the radius

Comment: @anuraag I think you want "*", not "/" there

Comment: @CarlWitthoft yes,you are right

Comment: @Joseph angular velocity=( angular frequency * 2πr). where r is the radius. Since angular frequency= no of cycles/sec. 1 cycle = 2πr